# How to filter every element except first in an array? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, filter, prototype

I have a 2D array which looks like this:

```
numbers = [[], [1,2,4], [], [1,2,6], []];  //Not always the same
```

Is it possible to use prototype.filter() to erase every empty array, **except** the first array in the index (numbers[0])? So far, haven't found an answer.

If not, should i use a for loop or there's another prototype function i'm not aware of?

Comment: Are you only looking to NOT remove `numbers[0]` or not remove the first empty array?  If so why not just take that out of the array completely and use it as a separate variable.

Comment: Was looking to NOT remove numbers[0]! Already solved. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
numbers.filter((subArray, index) => subArray.length > 0 || index === 0);
```

Comment: wait shouldnt that be `!= 0` ?

Comment: @tblev He want to include also the first element of array with `!= 0` you exclude it

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you filter for every array that is empty then add the first array back in afterward?

```
// Filter for only arrays with lengths greater than 0
myArray.filter(subArray=> subArray.length > 0);
// Add an empty array to the beginning of the array
myArray.unshift([]);
```

Comment: haha my comment points at the same thing :)

Comment: Working the data around the code on this one :-p